# Run-time error "Element not found" when creating New Excel.Application

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that opens Excel from Solidworks to pull part information from a table. Recently I'm getting this error when it hits the line "set xlApp = New Excel.Application"

The error is
Run-time error '-2147023728 (80070490)': Element not found.

I don't have any missing libraries, and I'm using excel.exe as my reference. (ver 16)
I get this same error if I try to run this simplified code from Outlook instead of Solidworks.

```
Dim xlApp As Object

Sub main()
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
End Sub
```

Other variants of code I've tried:

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

Sub main()
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
End Sub
```

Result: Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

If change this to:

```
Set xlApp = new Excel.Application
```

like I have in the previous example then I get the Element not found error. So, late-binding vs. early-binding has no effect.

This is all being tested with excel already running. VBA code inside Excel works fine unless I use that specific line. I can use "Application.ActiveWorkbook" inside Excel without error and without defining Application (because it's already Excel).

I have removed and reinstalled Office to no avail. Researching hasn't directed me to anything similar for other solutions to try.

Thanks in advance.
-Taylor

Comment: `GetObject` only works if the application is already open - was Excel running when you tried that?

Comment: [Similar problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-visual-basic-run-time-error-2147023728/3e8b2795-cd5e-42f2-b193-80b9e73765b1) here, though no viable solution provided.

Comment: Have you tried adding the version number? Or using `CreateObject` instead of `GetObject`? like `Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application.16")` It might help if there are multiple version installed.

Comment: @TimWilliams I did have Excel running when I tried the GetObject function.

Comment: @Toddleson I just tried with the version number. Adding a ".16" at the end of the New command throws a syntax error. The Get and CreateObject functions both gave me an ActiveX cannot create object error. As far as I can tell this is the only version. Desktop came with it installed 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue on some machines I support. Here was my solution, late binding was the answer for me.

```
Dim xlApp As Object

Sub main()
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Application.Visible = True
    'This line would create a blank workbook, but you could open an existing one here
    'xlApp.Workbooks.Add
End Sub
```

From there you could open the workbook you need and continue as normal.

Comment: @TRL has already commented that the CreateObject function isn't able to create the Excel App. It gives the "ActiveX cannot create object" error.

Comment: @Toddleson Neat. Clearly there are multiple possible causes for this, and it may help someone down the line.